# Higher-order functions in pyspark to generate streaming dataframe operations?

Tags: python, apache-spark

Let's say I've got a list of a lot of Kafka topics to listen to and table names to upsert into. So, I write this:

```
def upsert(df, tableName):
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("mergeTable")
  spark.sql(f'''
MERGE INTO {tableName}
USING mergeTable
ON {tableName}.Key = mergeTable.Key
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
{tableName}.Value = mergeTable.Value
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (Key, Value) VALUES
(mergeTable.Key, mergeTable.Value)
  ''')
def curryUpsert(df, tableName):
  def F(df, batchId):
    return upsert(df,tableName)
  return F
```

and then I call it like this:

```
for (topic, tableName) in a_big_list_of_tables_to_upsert_into:
  (
      spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("subscribe", topic)
      .load()  
      .writeStream
      .foreachBatch(curryUpsert(tableName))
      .outputMode("update")
      .start()
    )
```

I get this error: `Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation.`

Is there a way to create a spark streaming dataframe generator? I want to fan a collection out into an equal number of streaming datareaders. I could do this by writing each one by hand, but it seems like I should be able to write a function that spits them out for me, but spark magic keeps that from working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. The spark instance of the dataframe needs to invoke the sql, so instead of `spark.sql("your sql here")`, write this: `df._jdf.sparkSession().sql("your sql here")`